# Necessary and sufficient condition for $(x_1,...,x_n)$ to be a permutation of $(1,...,n)$ - Part II

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

This thread is following the question posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336273/a-necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-x-1-x-n-to-be-a-permutation-of) and seeks to find a generalization to the *test function* used in the previous question i.e. $f_a(x_1, \dotsc,x_n)=(x_1+a)\dotsb(x_n+a)$

At first, I propose this conjecture:
$\forall$ $n>0 \in \mathbb N$, $ \exists$ $p>0 \in \mathbb N$ such that
for any set of integers $(x_1,...,x_n)$  and  $1\leq x_i \leq n$:

$(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$ is a permutation of $(1,\dotsc,n)$ if and only if:
$x_1^p+\dotsb+x_n^p=1^p+\dotsb+n^p$

I checked this conjecture for $n=1,\dotsc,17$
The minimum values of $p$ are: $(1,1,2,2,2,4,5,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,7,7)$
Here the test function is $f_p(x_1, \dotsc,x_n)=x_1^p+\dotsb +x_n^p$

The question is then: assuming $f_p(x_1, \dotsc,x_n)$ is a symmetric function of n variables with a parameter $p$, what kind of properties must $f$ have  in order to be a *test function* i.e. to be able to say if $(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a permutation of $(1,...,n)$?
New examples ?

Comment: I wonder what sets $S$ of integer partitions of $n$ has the property that if one knows the values of $s_\lambda(x)$ for $\lambda \in S$, then one can deduce 'permutability' of the vector $x$. Here, $s_\lambda$ are the Schur functions.

Answer (score 2):

Your conjecture is true:
If $p$ is big enough then $(n-1)\cdot (n-1)^p<n^p$ and therefore $\lfloor \frac{x_1^p+\cdots+x_n^p}{n^p}\rfloor$ denotes the number of $i$ with $x_i=n$, hence from $x_1^p+\cdots + x_n^p=1^p+\cdots +n^p$ we see that this number is one as desired.
Next, if also $(n-2)\cdot(n-2)^p<(n-1)^p$, then $\lfloor \frac{x_1^p+\cdots+x_n^p-n^p}{(n-1)^p}\rfloor$ denotes the number of $i$ with $x_i=n-1$, and so on.
So all we need is $p$ such that $k^{p+1}<(k+1)^p$ for $1\le k\le n-1$. Divide by $k^p$ and take logarithms to see that it is sufficient to take $$p>\max_{1\le k<n}\frac{\ln k}{\ln(1+\frac1k)}\sim n\ln n.$$
*(This gives $p=50$ instead of $p=7$ for $n=17$, but who cares)*

Comment: Just one small question: if all $x_i$ are equal to $n-1$, we have $x_1^p + \dots + x_n^p= n \cdot (n-1)^p$. Hence I think the inequality $(n-1)\cdot (n-1)^p < n^p$ is formally not sufficient for the first step, I think for that we might need $n \cdot (n-1)^p < n^p$.